# Preferred way in Angular to trigger one API call (HTTP GET ) only when another API call has finished

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular, if I have one part of the screen populated by an HTTP GET request and another part of the screen populated by a completely different GET request, but the second request should only get called after the first completely finishes, what is the preferred way (i.e. best practice) to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess the issue is that there were a variety of ways to achieve this, but since I’m rather new to Angular I wanted to know if there was a “best practice” way. Seems like every post I find offers a slightly different take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a dependency on the first request while using [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to mutate the inner observable of the second request.

```
public firstResponse$ = this.http.get('api/endpoint').pipe(share());

public secondResponse$ = this.firstResponse$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.http.get('api/other-endpoint')));
```

This creates a stream that will ensure that the second request isn't triggered until the first request returns with a response.

Note the [`share()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) operator which will avoid making multiple requests when subscribed to multiple times.

Comment: as a bonus, switchMap also cancels the first stream when that part completes, which prevents inner subscription memory leaks. also, don't forget to subscribe to secondResponse$ in order to start the stream.

Answer (score 0):

In your ngOnInIt:

```
ngOnInIt{
this.firstResponse() //assuming the name of the first method is firstResponse.
}
```

In your ts:

```
firstResponse(){
//Inside your subscription
this.secondResponse() //assuming the name of the second method is secondResponse.
}
```